xUbuntu POST not turning on screens
When I am turning on my desktop, with the latest Xubuntu, my screens don't light up - so, I obviously can't log in. However, with enough unsuccessful attempts, they will, once in a while, engage the monitors, so I can login (so I copied off a bunch of important data, while I still could).
It may be purely a hardware issue (it doesn't look like its even getting to the point of loading the OS)... Are there any suggestions on what I might look at to resolve this?
I am only thinking about "replacing the motherboard." Hopefully, there is a less drastic resolution.

Firstly I'd try and boot into your machine firmware (ie. BIOS/settings) and see if you can operate it from there..  If you can't do that, you have hardware issues... Next boot live media that is very different to your installed OS (Xubuntu 24.04 LTS I gather) as I'd see if it operates identically there or not; being live you can try numerous different software stacks, and not just the 6.8 kernel you're using now.. If you find some are good, others are not it may not be hardware, but if they're all the same it's hardware almost certainly...  This isn't a hardware support platform though

Your details are not exactly clear (being vague), but I have found different hardware reacts different to certain software stacks; eg. I have multiple GPUs on my box & other boxes & I get variations in boot depending on machine firmware, OS & especially kernel stack in regards grub (boot loader) & DM (lightdm for Xubuntu usually) and what shows or doesn't show... Starting at runlevel 1 is usually more consistent, but your details are vague & highlight mostly hardware anyway (you give little details as to what you've tried in regards software)
